# PHP get_file_contents post session page navigation

Tags: php, session, post, navigation

I got a homework to retrieve the 2nd results page of http://wiki.webo-facto.com from a search post data. Like this:

```
 $postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'q' => 'catalogue',
        'submit' => 'searchbutton'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://wiki.webo-facto.com/', false, $context);
```

No problem.
My sensei said that:"Once a search is done, the search criteria is stored in session. It is this session that makes navigation work".
Then, from the same script i add `$_SESSION['post']=$postdata;
header('Location: getsecondpage.php')`
 All of this stored in `poster.php` .
Now Time to retrive the second page in `getsecondpage.php`:

```
session_start();

$postdata = $_SESSION['postdata'];
$opts2 = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
    $context2 = stream_context_create($opts2);
$result2 = file_get_contents('http://wiki.webo-facto.com/resultspage-2.html', false, $context2);
    echo $result2;
```

return the results of the 1st page that are not what i want.
Your suggestion will be very helpful.
Notice: that i have also start the session from `poster.php`.(code not visible).
Sorry for my bad english, Im franco-saxon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *sensei* is right, the search criteria is stored in session BUT in REMOTE SERVER SESSION. So what you have to do is "tell the server your session cookie" to be able to save and load it!

So for the first query we will do a POST with our search criteria AND telling the remote server our session name and id:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 
            "Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id()."\r\n",
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
```

And for the second one, server already stored our query in SESSION so we do not need to send it again. So we'll do a GET. Also telling server our session name and session id.

```
$opts2 = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . 
            "Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id()."\r\n",
    )
);
```

And that's it!